# Pass and store interface implementation

Tags: c++, interface, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Let's assume we have interface `selector_interface_t` and implementation of this interface `pin_selector_t`.

```
class selector_interface_t
{
    public:
        virtual void select(uint8_t address) = 0;
        virtual void deselect() = 0;
};

class pin_selector_t : public selector_interface_t
{
    private:
        uint8_t mask;

    public:
        pin_selector_t(uint8_t mask);
        void select(uint8_t address);
        void deselect();
};
```

And now we want to pass object witch implements this interface to class `myclass_t` and store for future use by other `myclass_t` methods (eg. `strobe`).

```
class myclass_t
{
    private:
        selector_interface_t * selector;

    public:
        myclass_t(selector_interface_t & selector);
        void strobe(uint8_t pin);
};

myclass_t::myclass_t(selector_interface_t & selector) // : selector(selector)
{
    // ...
}

void myclass_t::strobe(uint8_t pin)
{
    this->selector->select(pin);
    this->selector->deselect();
}
```

The only way is pass implementation by pointer or by reference. I prefer second solution and pass by reference. But I cannot simply store this reference in `myclass_t` object because of lifetime of object with interface implementation. It would be better to make a copy. But I cannot have `selector_interface_t` field member. I can only have reference or pointer to this type. On the other way I'd like to avoid using malloc. What can I do with it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are the one who creates the selector_interface_t type then you can store it inside a shared_ptr and have the myclass_t class hold a weak_ptr or shared_ptr to the interface.

If you are not the one who creates selector_interface_t then I assume you have other means of keeping the object alive, wrap it in a class that manages the lifetime and that object wrap in shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't guarantee that the implementation has the right lifetime, then you need to manage it, which means dynamically allocating it. (Using `new`, not `malloc`.)

I would strongly suggest using either `shared_ptr<selector_interface_t>` or `unique_ptr<selector_interface_t>` - depending on whether or not you ever want to share implementation objects between clients. You then get correct code with very little effort.